# Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

For $1\leq p<n$, we define the Sobolev conjugate of$p$ as $p^{\ast}=\frac{np}{n-p}$.

Recall the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality $$||u||_{L^{p^{\ast}}(\mathbb{R}^n)}\leq C ||\nabla u||_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)}$$ for some constant $C$ depending only on $n$ and $p$ for any function $u\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

From this, one derives easily the following estimate for $W^{1,p}$: let $U$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{r}^n$, an open disk say. Assume that $1\leq p<n$ and let $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$. Then $u\in L^{p^{\ast}}(U)$ with $$||u||_{L^{p^{\ast}}(U)}\leq C||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)}$$

I came accross the following inequality $$||u||_{L^2(\partial U)}\leq C||u||_{L^p(U)}^{1-1/p} ||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)}^{1/p}, \quad u\in W^{1,p}(U)$$

Is this a consequence of the previous inequalities?

I am even confused about the appropriateness of the 'u' in the left hand side: I would expect the restriction to $\partial U$ of a function $v\in W^{1,p}(U)$. Since the restriction operator $\tau:W^{1,p}(U)\rightarrow L^2(\partial U)$ is continuous, then $$||v_{|\partial U}||_{L^2(\partial U)}=||\tau(u)||_{L^2(\partial U)}\leq C||u||_{W^{1,2}(U)}$$ and from here I am wondering if the inequalities above shed some light.

Comment: If I may ask, where did this inequality come from?

Comment: Your statement of Gagliardo-Nirenberg is wrong: the right hand side should have $L^p$ and note $L^{p^*}$.

Comment: Apologies, I fixed it. I appreciate a lot your observations below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p \geq 2$, then an appropriate version of the Hölder inequality shows that for $U$ bounded, $L^p(U) \hookrightarrow L^2(U)$, hence $W^{1,p}\hookrightarrow W^{1,2} \hookrightarrow L^2$ using the trace inequality. So you have

$$ \|u\|_2 \leq \|u\|_2^{1-1/p}\|u\|_2^{1/p} \lesssim \|u\|_p^{1-1/p} \|u\|^{1/p}_{W^{1,2}} \lesssim \|u\|^{1-1/p}_p \|u\|^{1/p}_{W^{1,p}} $$

*which does not require passing through the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality*. (Though one can argue that the proof of the GN inequality can be recycled to prove the trace theorem, so the two aren't completely unrelated.)

The interesting case is when $p < 2$, in which your estimate follows partially from the generalized Sobolev imbedding theorems (which allows also for trace estimates). See, for example, Theorem 4.12 Case C of Robert Adams' *Sobolev Spaces*. In particular the numerology requires $p \leq 2 \leq (n-1)p / (n-p)$ which implies

$$ \frac{2n}{n+1} \leq p \leq 2 $$

must hold for the classical trace theorem $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^2(\partial\Omega)$. (If you believe in fractional Sobolev spaces, then you can also "obtain" the above by combining a fractional version of Gagliardo-Niremberg from $W^{1,p}\hookrightarrow H^s$ for some $s > 1/2$ and using the fractional trace theorem $H^s(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^2(\partial\Omega)$; note that this route naively will require the lower bound on $p$ to be a *strict* inequality due to the failure of $H^{1/2}(\Omega)\not\hookrightarrow L^2(\partial\Omega)$.) In particular, for dimension $n > 1$ the $L^1$ endpoint is not covered by this theorem.

This failure at $L^1$ is not a problem of the method: it is a genuine failure of the inequality. Consider the function in two dimension $u(x,y) = \left[ (x-1)^2 + y^2\right]^{1/4}$, which is just a translated version of the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$. It is not $L^2$ integrable when restricted to the circle, since it has a Logarithmic singularity at $(1,0)$. But $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}$ is certainly $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, and its derivative which has a $\frac{1}{r^{3/2}}$ singularity is also $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. (The same example also works in arbitrary $n \geq 2$; you can either use the same principle via functions like translates of $\frac{1}{r^{(n-1)/2}}$, or just argue through the method of descent.)